# Spring Hibernate Mongodb autowiring sessionfactory

Tags: spring, mongodb, hibernate, autowired, sessionfactory

How to integrate spring hibernate and mongodb so that the sessionfactory can be autowired.
I am using hibernate-ogm-mongodb 5.1 and Spring 4.3.8

Comment: Do you have some code to show? Any particular tutorial you followed?

Comment: Currently this is the below snippet I use, but this is not what I want, though this gets the job done, I am trying to understand if there is a better option.Configuration configuration = new OgmConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
//     SERVICE_REGISTRY = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
     SERVICE_REGISTRY = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
     SESSION_FACTORY = configuration.buildSessionFactory(SERVICE_REGISTRY);... say using autowiring for sessionfacto